# WinForms in PowerShell not able to display Unicode character

Tags: powershell, winforms, unicode

I created a WinForms GUI in PowerShell (version 5.1.2) as below.
I wanted to display the [Unicode ship icon](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F6F3) on the button.
However, it is always showing a square symbol instead of a ship icon:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

$button.Text = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x0001F6F3)

$form.AcceptButton = $button
$form.Controls.Add($button)

$form.TopMost = $true
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    #...
}
```

This is the result:
[image: button icon]

This is what I expect:
[image: button icon]

There could be something wrong with the Unicode Encoding with WinForms in PowerShell, but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want your Controls to render Unicode text and improve support for international fonts, you always call [Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault) (before any Form is created).
Setting `false` means that the rendering is *not compatible* with pre-Whidbey (.NET Fx 2.0) GDI+ rendering, using GDI ([TextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer)) with [ClearType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/cleartype/) support instead.

I also suggest enabling [Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/rendering-controls-with-visual-styles) by default, calling [Application.EnableVisualStyles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles)

Specifying an *active* DpiAwareness may also improve the overall aspect.
Here I'm calling [SetProcessDpiAwareness()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness), specifying [PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-process_dpi_awareness) as the adopted mode. Modify or remove if not required / unwanted.

For example:

Note: if you're using the Windows PowerShell ISE, this may not work when run from the IDE.
You have to execute the script through either `powershell.exe` or `pwsh.exe`

```
using namespace System.Drawing
using namespace System.Windows.Forms

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault($false)

$code = @"
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shcore.dll")]
    public static extern int SetProcessDpiAwareness(int dpiAwarenessMode);
"@
$PInvoke = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Name "PInvoke" -PassThru
$null = $PInvoke::SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)

$form = [Form] @{
    AutoScaleMode = [AutoScaleMode]::Dpi;
    ClientSize = [Point]::new(200, 200);
    StartPosition = [FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;
    Text = "Visual Styles";
}

$button = [Button] @{
    Font = [Font]::new("Segoe UI", 20)
    Location = [Point]::new(20, 20)
    Size = [Size]::new(40, 40)
    Text = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x0001F6F3)
    UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
}

$form.Controls.Add($button)
$form.ShowDialog()
```